# Mesh smoothing/minimal surface algorithm, ideally in python

Tags: python, algorithm, computational-geometry, mesh

I am in need of an algorithm for approximating a minimal surface (with some added constraints) starting from an initial triangular 3D mesh. For now, I would be quite satisfied with a reproduction of what is implemented in Blender as "smooth vertices".

I believe that effectively one would move every node in the direction of the normal vectors (or edges?) of neighboring faces, probably weighing them by the adjacent angle. But I am not sure about what really matches the minimal surface criterion best. In addition, I would love to have a reference implementation to see how others handle the stepsize/convergence and "in-face-smoothing" issues.

I am working with python, but in the end it is more about the algorithm than about a preexisting suitable implementation.

Comment: You mean like subdivision? _Eg_ [Catmull-Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) or [Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_subdivision_surface).

Answer (score 2):

A simple algorithm to get started is known as [Laplacian Smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_smoothing). For each vertex, average all surrounding vertices, and move it towards that average by some factor between 0 and 1.

Reference implementation from [polyform](https://github.com/EliCDavis/polyform/blob/main/modeling/meshops/laplacian_smoothing.go#L30)

```golang
func LaplacianSmooth(m modeling.Mesh, attribute string, iterations int, smoothingFactor float64) modeling.Mesh {

    lut := m.VertexNeighborTable()

    oldVertices := m.Float3Attribute(attribute)
    vertices := make([]vector3.Float64, oldVertices.Len())
    for i := range vertices {
        vertices[i] = oldVertices.At(i)
    }

    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
        for vi, vertex := range vertices {
            var sum vector3.Float64

            for vn := range lut.Lookup(vi) {
                sum = sum.Add(vertices[vn])
            }

            vertices[vi] = vertex.Add(sum.
                    DivByConstant(float64(lut.Count(vi))).
                    Sub(vertex).
                    Scale(smoothingFactor))
        }
    }

    return m.SetFloat3Attribute(attribute, vertices)
}
```